# What is the meaning of "vice president"?

Tags: meaning

Young woman Regina telling to Peter about his husband that he 
mixed up in something terrible and she must do someting about it.

> Regina: It doesn't sound like the sort of thing a young woman can
>   handle by herself.
>
> Peter: How about making me **vice president** in charge of cheering you
>   up?

Comment: Have you looked this up in a dictionary? --He uses the title as a joke: the 'meaning' is in the PP "in charge of cheering you up".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used with a job title, the word "vice" means "next in authority."

- Vice president
- Vice admiral
- Viceroy (literally, "Vice Royalty")